# Avoid duplicate entires at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a growing application and my concern is that when you purchase an order, we delegate it to a person. However as we're scaling now I'd like to find a solution where a person can be delegated two orders at the same time, if two different customers purchase at the same time.

Currently our order goes through a state machine (AASM) where it connects:

```
event :connect, after: :find_person do
  transitions from: :pending, to: :connecting
end
```

and the `find_person` looks like this:

```
  def find_person
    person = Person.where(aasm_state: 'available').order('RANDOM()').first
    if person
      person.requested!
      create_order_request(person: person)
    else
      person_unavailable!
    end
 end
```

now how can I avoid that if two entries come in at the same time that they won't both be delegated to this person. If a person is found, I move their status to requested. Which means that they can't receive a new order (because I look for only people that are 'available').

Comment: One thing you can do, is sending all new orders to a queue, so basically all orders are waiting in line to get assigned.

Comment: I do process each order as a background job doing this:
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      order = Order.find_by(guid: guid)
      return unless order
      order.connect!
    end

might this actually be the solution as-well

Comment: You might want to look at this https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs to know explor other options.